# I have created a leaderboard using python but my code prints in a single line. I want it to print each element separately like in a leaderboard format

Tags: python, python-3.x

this is my code

```
file=open("leaderboard.txt", "a")
file.write(str(winnerpts) + ", " + winneruser + "\n")
file.close()

with open('leaderboard.txt', 'r') as f:
    leaderboard = [line.replace('\n','') for line in f.readlines()]
    leaderboard.sort(reverse=True)

for idx, item in enumerate(leaderboard):
    if item.split(', ')[1] == winneruser[1] and int(item.split(', ')[1]) < int(winneruser[9]):
        leaderboard[idx] = '{}, {}'.format(winneruser[1], winneruser[9])
    else:
        pass

with open('leaderboard.txt', 'w') as f:
    for item in leaderboard:
        f.write("%s\n" % item)

with open("leaderboard.txt") as leaderboard:
    head = [next(leaderboard).split() for x in range(5)]
    print(head)
```

this is the result

```
[['98,', 'ioi'], ['90,', 'io'], ['72,', 'io'], ['72,', 'io'], ['67,', 'ioi']]
```

i want it to print something like this:

```
['98,', 'ioi']
['90,', 'io']
['72,', 'io'] 
['72,', 'io'] 
['67,', 'ioi']
```

if it is possible can the square brackets also be removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume you have this list `elements`like below:

```
elements = [['98,', 'ioi'], ['90,', 'io'], ['72,', 'io'], ['72,', 'io'], ['67,', 'ioi']]
```

You have to go through your list to achieve your result.

```
for element in elements:
    print(element)
```

You will get:

```
['98,', 'ioi']
['90,', 'io']
['72,', 'io']
['72,', 'io']
['67,', 'ioi']
```

> **Update**

Your code looks like:

```
with open("leaderboard.txt") as leaderboard:
    head = [next(leaderboard).split() for x in range(5)]
    print(head)
```

You have to do this:

```
with open("leaderboard.txt") as leaderboard:
    head = [next(leaderboard).split() for x in range(5)]

    for element in head:
        print(element)
```

> **Update**

```
with open("leaderboard.txt") as leaderboard:
    head = [next(leaderboard).split() for x in range(5)]

    for element in head:
        info = element[0] + " " + element[1] # add this line
        print(info)
```

> **Output**

```
98, ioi
90, io
72, io
72, io
67, ioi
```

Comment: Thanks so much. It works perfectly.                                                                                                                                         is their anyway that the square brackets and quote marks can be removed when printing?

Comment: If, it works, you have to vote and accept my answer. Others people can benefit from that.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to remove the square brackets and the quotes...

Comment: how would you do that though. sorry i'm a relatively new coder. Also i did but since im new i dont think the vote actually shows

Comment: The solution of @RohanSharma is cool. But I provide you a really nice one...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of printing the list (head) directly, just print its elements.

```
for i in range(len(head)):
    print(head[i][0] + ' ' + head[i][1])
```

This will print the list (head) as:

```
98, ioi
90, io
72, io
72, io
67, ioi
```

Comment: wow this has been a massive help for me. thank you guys a lot